# Select x and y coordinates by trimming unwanted characters

Tags: sql-server, substring, character, coordinates, trim

I have a SQL table which contains a geometry column. This column takes the format of:

POINT (323432.71888947 523412.81388917)

I want to do a SELECT statement so I can return the X and Y coordinates WITHOUT any decimals. E.g. from the above I would want to return in two different X and Y columns:

323432

523412

I am struggling to find the best way to do this. I guess using SUBSTRING is the way forwards but i'm not having much luck.

This is using SQL Server.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server...?

Comment: @GMB - thanks I have done this now

Comment: In SQL Server, below solution by @AirlineDog should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you :

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::Parse('POINT (323432.71888947 523412.81388917)');  

SELECT cast(@g.STX as int) , cast(@g.STY as int)
```

Simply adjust your table to the query.